# Вложенные селекторы влияют на скорость загрузки сайта?

Tags: css, sass

Есть sass:

```
#header {
    @include position(fixed, 0 null null 0);
    width: 326px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #1F1916;
    text-align: center;

    .top {
        @include position(absolute, 0 null null 0);
        width: 100%;

        .logo {
            background-color: #fff;
            display: block;
            padding: 50px 0 44px;

            img {
                width: 185px;
                height: 71px;
            }
        }
    }

    .bottom {
        @include position(absolute, null null 0 0);
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

В результате:

```
#header .top .logo img {}
```

Влияет ли это на что-то, если да - то в какую сторону?

Comment: Пара статей: http://webhitech.ru/articles/selectors-performance-part-1, http://frontender.info/css-performance-revisited-selectors-bloat-expensive-styles/

Answer (score 4):

`#header .top .logo img {}`

1. Браузер читает селекторы справа налево. Т.е. браузер выберет все картинки, потом узнает у которых у них есть родитель с классом `.logo`, потом с классом `.top`... Ну вы поняли.

Сейчас, браузеры довольно шустры, но всё же: разумнее будет задать отдельный класс для конкретного элемента (картинка в Вашем случае), например, `.header_logo_img`.

2. Использование `id` в css - не круто. Да и такие селекторы типа `#header .top .logo img` - имеют очень большой "вес". Их будет трудно "перебить" в каскаде стилей ниже.

Советую Вам почитать про методики написания классов, например, БЭМ. А также установить линтер, например, SCSS-Lint.

Comment: А что значит "Трудно перебить"?  Для чего-то ID придумали в спецификации CSS, тем не менее....

Comment: @labris https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/ - ознакомьтесь, пожалуйста. Особенно с частью "Calculating CSS Specificity Value".
И, кстати, ID - это не спецификация CSS, а HTML.

Comment: Насчет весовых значений ID - не спорю, просто зачем их потом перебивать при корректной логике? "Круто" или "некруто" - тут не важно, важна возможность использования элементов с уникальным ID, хотя бы для того же getElementbyID. Другое дело, что злоупотреблять ID не стоит. И все же поправлю - ID селектор используется в спецификации CSS, начиная с CSS1. Вот тут хорошее сравнение ID и class по скорости рендеринга - https://webo.in/articles/habrahabr/38-css-efficiency-tests-3/ , классы выигрывают :)

Comment: "хотя бы для того же getElementbyID" - вот для js и нужен id.

Comment: Собственно, ID и появился в HTML 4.01 для использования с CSS и Javascript, в версии HTML 3.02 понятие ID отсутствовало.

Answer (score 3):

Старайтесь избегать больших вложенности,  код плохо читается, лучше давайте класс для img. Опять же, большие вложенности, большой размер файла css, как-то так.

Comment: #header .top .logo img {} это перебор? sass у меня отлично читается

Answer (score 2):

Поскольку конечный CSS, как я предполагаю, будет минифицирован (до полной нечитаемости), значимой разницы нет.
Разница, скажем, в 10 кБ (достаточно большой объем для css файла) совершенно несущественна (при загрузке занимает порядка миллисекунды при нормальном интернете и незаметна даже при dial-up).